# Grokking Timsort

Tags: java, python, algorithm, sorting, timsort

There's a (relatively) new sort on the block called Timsort. It's been used as Python's list.sort, and is now going to be [the new Array.sort in Java 7](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)).

There's [some documentation](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt) and a [tiny Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) describing the high-level properties of the sort and some low-level performance evaluations, but I was curious if anybody can provide some pseudocode to illustrate what Timsort is doing, exactly, and what are the key things that make it zippy. (Esp. with regard to the cited paper, "Optimistic Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity.")

(See also [related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154504/is-timsort-general-purpose-or-python-specific).)

Comment: This link http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt from the earlier question is pretty clear. It's a tweaked and optimized merge sort.

Comment: I actually meant to link to that in my "some documentation" link. Fixed. My question was specifically a response to that document - I didn't find it to be at all useful in understanding Timsort from a pseudocode-ish level.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quoting the relevant portion from a now deleted blog post: [Visualising Sorting Algorithms: Python's timsort](https://web.archive.org/web/20170713165314/https://corte.si/posts/code/timsort/index.html)

> The business-end of timsort is a mergesort that operates on runs of pre-sorted elements. A minimum run length minrun is chosen to make sure the final merges are as balanced as possible - for 64 elements, minrun happens to be 32. Before the merges begin, a single pass is made through the data to detect pre-existing runs of sorted elements. Descending runs are handled by simply reversing them in place. If the resultant run length is less than minrun, it is boosted to minrun using insertion sort. On a shuffled array with no significant pre-existing runs, this process looks exactly like our guess above: pre-sorting blocks of minrun elements using insertion sort, before merging with merge sort.

[...]

- timsort finds a descending run, and reverses the run in-place. This is done directly on the array of pointers, so seems "instant" from our vantage point.
- The run is now boosted to length minrun using insertion sort.
- No run is detected at the beginning of the next block, and insertion sort is used to sort the entire block. Note that the sorted elements at the bottom of this block are not treated specially - timsort doesn't detect runs that start in the middle of blocks being boosted to minrun.
- Finally, mergesort is used to merge the runs.

Comment: Thanks. This is probably pretty as close as I'll get to what I asked for. My take-away is that it does prepares blocks ('minruns') of 32 elts with insertion sort and reverse-in-place.

Answer (score 8):

This change went through the [core-libs mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/) when it went in so there is some discussion and useful links there.  Here's the [web rev](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Emartin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/) with code review changes and also the [original patch](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Emartin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/timsort.patch).

The comments in the code say:

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive,
> iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons
> when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the
> performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is
> randomly ordered.  If the input array is nearly sorted, the
> implementation requires approximately n comparisons.
> Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted
> input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input
> arrays.
>
> The implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and
> descending order in its input array, and can take advantage of
> ascending and descending order in different parts of the the same
> input array.  It is well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays:
> simply concatenate the arrays and sort the resulting array.
> The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python
> [TimSort](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt).  It uses techiques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic
> Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the
> Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474,
> January 1993.

Buried in there is the [very useful link to the Python implementation details](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt), and I think that's a great place to start, followed by the code.  To be incredibly high level about it, timsort improves performance by noticing runs of sorted data and taking advantage of that structure during the sort.

Comment: I actually meant to link to that in my "some documentation" link. Fixed. My question was specifically a response to that document - I didn't find it to be at all useful in understanding Timsort from a pseudocode-ish level.