# How do python define builtin sorted( ) two same elements

Tags: python

How do python define the behavior of  builtin sorted( ) when two elements are the same?
Do they get an undeterministic order?

Comment: Python's sort is stable.

Comment: This is referred to as "stability", and Timsort (the default sorting algorithm in CPython) *is* stable; two equal elements will have the same order in the output that they do in the input. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19587279/3001761).