# Why does .Net use Quicksort instead of Timsort?

Tags: .net, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, timsort

I've read that Timsort is better than Quicksort both in the best and the worst case, although it uses a bit more memory. Is there a specific reason why the built in .Sort() methods use Quicksort or is it just that it isn't implemented yet?

Comment: This thread may be a part of the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770230/comparison-between-timsort-and-quicksort

Comment: "is it just that it isn't implemented yet?" presumes that it will be implemented at some point -  but you've already identified that there is a *trade-off* in using it. If Quicksort is "good enough" for most uses, you need to come up with a compelling reason to switch.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That trade-off seems very small to me compared to the advantages of Timsort (usually faster) especially today, when you have plenty of RAM for a sort. And why use "good enough" algorithms, when you can use the best?

Comment: @Bidou Thanks, that link is very useful. So I guess the answer is because Quicksort is much simpler and it uses less RAM (which I don't really get as Timsort only uses n instead of log(n), which doesn't really matter with 4 or 8 Gigs of RAM istalled).

Comment: Microsoft list.sort is introsort (quick then heap sort if needed), which I assume is the same or similar to Microsoft std::sort. stable_sort() is basically a bottom up merge sort, but assuming it's similar to std::stable_sort(), it uses a temp array 1/2 the size of the source array, sorts both halves, then ends up with first half in temp, second half in second half of source array, then does a final merge of temp and second half back into source array.