# (java) Quick sort to sort a number-char pair by number first, then char

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I've modified the algorithm found here: http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort

To work with my `Node` class:

```
public class Node
{
    public int frequency;
    public char value;
}
```

Basically, it should sort by frequency first, then if the frequencies are the same, look at the char value.

This is my code:

```
public static int partition(Node arr[], int left, int right)
{
      int i = left, j = right;
      Node tmp;
      int pivot = (left + right) / 2;

      while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i].frequency < arr[pivot].frequency)
                  i++;
            while (arr[j].frequency > arr[pivot].frequency)
                  j--;
            if (i <= j) {

                if (arr[i].frequency == arr[j].frequency)
                {
                    if (arr[i].value > arr[j].value)
                    {
                        tmp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = tmp;                           
                    }
                }
                else //(arr[i].frequency > arr[j].frequency)
                {
                    tmp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = tmp;                           
                }

                i++;
                j--;
            }
      };

      return i;
}

public static void quickSort(Node arr[], int left, int right) {
      int index = partition(arr, left, right);
      if (left < index - 1)
            quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
      if (index < right)
            quickSort(arr, index, right);
}
```

Right now it *does* work, but it misses a letter every now and then. Just looking to get it working properly.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

EDIT: Thank you to everyone who answered! I ended up using the Comparable suggestion. It sorts very well now.

Comment: Any reason not to use the built-in `Arrays.sort`?

Comment: Just an idea, wouldn't it be easier to implement [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) on `Node` and use `compareTo` in the sort and not have to complicate the sort code with the complexities of figuring out how to compare nodes? That would also allow for using existing, built in, sorts unless there is a very good reason to implement your own.

Comment: Are the built-in sorts just as fast? I'm under a bit of a time crunch

Comment: Yes, they are fast. But more importantly, *they are correct.*

Comment: The ability to provide your own IComparable for custom classes is there to solve exactly this type of problem. It takes about 5 minutes to learn and 1 minute to do, and armed with this knowledge you can sort any class by any rule you can devise. Definitely something you need to know; otherwise you will have these sorts of problems over and over again.

Comment: Thanks guys, ended up going with the Comparable route. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here 5 way to do this(you can add more):
as this 
http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort
said + your code with some edit:

```
package AR;

class Node {
    public int frequency;
    public char value;

    public Node(int frequency, char value) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

final class Sort {

    int partition(Node arr[], int left, int right) {
        int i = left, j = right;
        Node tmp;
        Node pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j) {
            while (i <= j && (arr[i].frequency < pivot.frequency || (arr[i].frequency == pivot.frequency && arr[i].value < pivot.value)))
                i++;
            while (i <= j && (arr[j].frequency > pivot.frequency || (arr[j].frequency == pivot.frequency && arr[j].value > pivot.value)))
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void quickSort(Node arr[], int left, int right) {
        if (left > right) return;
        int index = partition(arr, left, right);
        if (left < index - 1)
            quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
        if (index < right)
            quickSort(arr, index, right);
    }
}

final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node[] ns = new Node[]{new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'c'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(0, 'z'), new Node(1, 'z')};
        int n = ns.length;
        Sort cl = new Sort();
        cl.quickSort(ns, 0, n - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("(" + ns[i].frequency + "," + ns[i].value + "), ");
            //(0,z), (1,b), (1,b), (1,b), (1,z), (8,a), (8,a), (8,a), (10,a), (10,a), (10,a), (10,b), (10,b), (10,c),
        }
    }
}
```

//in  @Debosmit Ray   way: (just change int to T) using Generics in Java::

```
package AR;

class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    public int frequency;
    public char value;

    public Node(int frequency, char value) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        if (this.frequency > o.frequency) return 1;
        if (this.frequency < o.frequency) return -1;
        if (this.value > o.value) return 1;
        if (this.value < o.value) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}

final class Sort<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    int partition(T arr[], int left, int right) {
        int i = left, j = right;
        T tmp;
        T pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j) {
            while (i <= j && arr[i].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
                i++;
            while (i <= j && arr[j].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void quickSort(T arr[], int left, int right) {
        if (left > right) return;
        int index = partition(arr, left, right);
        if (left < index - 1)
            quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
        if (index < right)
            quickSort(arr, index, right);
    }
}

final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node[] ns = new Node[]{new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'c'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(0, 'z'), new Node(1, 'z')};
        int n = ns.length;
        Sort cl = new Sort();
        cl.quickSort(ns, 0, n - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("(" + ns[i].frequency + "," + ns[i].value + "), ");
            //(0,z), (1,b), (1,b), (1,b), (1,z), (8,a), (8,a), (8,a), (10,a), (10,a), (10,a), (10,b), (10,b), (10,c),
        }
    }
}
```

//place pivot in left side of array, and compare in one loop, like this:

```
package AR;

class Node {
    public int frequency;
    public char value;
    public Node(int frequency, char value) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
final class Main {
    static int partition(Node[] arr, int left, int right) {
        int i = left+1, j = right;
        Node tmp;
        int pivot =  left  ;
        while (i <= j) {
            while (i <= j && (arr[i].frequency < arr[pivot].frequency || (arr[i].frequency == arr[pivot].frequency && arr[i].value <= arr[pivot].value)))
                i++;
            while (i <= j && (arr[j].frequency > arr[pivot].frequency || (arr[j].frequency == arr[pivot].frequency && arr[j].value > arr[pivot].value)))
                j--;
            if (i > j) break;
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
        tmp = arr[pivot];
        arr[pivot] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
        return j;
    }
    public static void quickSort(Node arr[], int left, int right) {
        if (left >= right) return;
        int i = partition(arr, left, right);
        quickSort(arr, left, i - 1);
        quickSort(arr, i + 1, right);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node[] ns = new Node[]{new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(0, 'z'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(1, 'z')};
        int n = ns.length;
        quickSort(ns, 0, n - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("(" + ns[i].frequency + "," + ns[i].value + "), ");
            //(0,z), (1,b), (1,b), (1,b), (1,z), (8,a), (8,a), (8,a), (10,a), (10,a), (10,a), (10,b), (10,b), (10,b),
        }
    }
}
```

//@Debosmit Ray    way to compare is very nice and it simplifies the code:

```
package AR;
class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    public int frequency;
    public char value;
    public Node(int frequency, char value) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        if (this.frequency > o.frequency) return 1;
        if (this.frequency < o.frequency) return -1;
        if (this.value > o.value) return 1;
        if (this.value < o.value) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
final class Main {
    static void swap(Node[] arr, int i, int j) {
        Node temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    static int partition(Node[] arr, int left, int right) {
        int i = left;
        Node pivot = arr[left++];
        while (left <= right) {
            while (left <= right && arr[left].compareTo(pivot) <= 0) left++;
            while (left <= right && arr[right].compareTo(pivot) > 0) right--;
            if (left > right)break;
            swap(arr, left++, right--);
        }
        swap(arr, i, right);
        return right;
    }
    public static void quickSort(Node arr[], int left, int right) {
        if (left >= right) return;
        int i = partition(arr, left, right);
        quickSort(arr, left, i - 1);
        quickSort(arr, i + 1, right);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node[] ns = new Node[]{new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(0, 'z'), new Node(1, 'z')};
        int n = ns.length;
        quickSort(ns, 0, n - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("(" + ns[i].frequency + "," + ns[i].value + "), ");
            //(0,z), (1,b), (1,b), (1,b), (1,z), (8,a), (8,a), (8,a), (10,a), (10,a), (10,a), (10,b), (10,b), (10,b), 
        }
    }
}
```

//using Generics in Java:

```
package AR;

class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    public int frequency;
    public char value;

    public Node(int frequency, char value) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        if (this.frequency > o.frequency) return 1;
        if (this.frequency < o.frequency) return -1;
        if (this.value > o.value) return 1;
        if (this.value < o.value) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}

final class Sort<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    void swap(T[] arr, int i, int j) {
        T temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }

    int partition(T[] arr, int left, int right) {
        int i = left;
        T pivot = arr[left++];
        while (left <= right) {
            while (left <= right && arr[left].compareTo(pivot) <= 0) left++;
            while (left <= right && arr[right].compareTo(pivot) > 0) right--;
            if (left > right) break;
            swap(arr, left++, right--);
        }
        swap(arr, i, right);
        return right;
    }

    public void quickSort(T arr[], int left, int right) {
        if (left >= right) return;
        int i = partition(arr, left, right);
        quickSort(arr, left, i - 1);
        quickSort(arr, i + 1, right);
    }

}

final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node[] ns = new Node[]{new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'c'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(10, 'a'), new Node(10, 'b'), new Node(8, 'a'), new Node(1, 'b'), new Node(0, 'z'), new Node(1, 'z')};
        int n = ns.length;
        Sort cl = new Sort();
        cl.quickSort(ns, 0, n - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("(" + ns[i].frequency + "," + ns[i].value + "), ");
            //(0,z), (1,b), (1,b), (1,b), (1,z), (8,a), (8,a), (8,a), (10,a), (10,a), (10,a), (10,b), (10,b), (10,c),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment here is not true:

```
            else //(arr[i].frequency > arr[j].frequency)
```

The if-branch checks if the frequencies are the same, so in the else you still have to check if they are in the right order before swapping them.

I would suggest writing a separate function to compare nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you move comparing 2 `Node` objects to a different method, or make `Node` comparable. I will demonstrate the second option here.

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    public int frequency;
    public char value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        if(this.frequency < o.frequency)
            return -1;
        else if(this.frequency > o.frequency)
            return 1;
        else {
            if(this.value < o.value)
                return -1;
            else if(this.value > o.value)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, instead of having to check both the fields while doing a comparison for quick sort, you can simply do something like `if(arr[i].compareTo(arr[j]) < 0`. Let me know if this helps. If not, I can help with some more code.

For sorting, I would suggest using `Arrays.sort(arr)`, now that you have your `Comparable` implemented. **Edit**. For arrays of primitives in Java, this function uses a Dual-Pivot Quicksort, which is quite cool. For arrays of Objects, `TimSort` is used. [[docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29)] [[TimSort vs QuickSort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19587279/1692706)]

Comment: "this function uses a Dual-Pivot Quicksort" - do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Joni Yes sir. Let me add that.

Comment: @Joni. Made a bit of an error. It uses `TimSort`, **not** a `Dual-Pivot Quicksort`. Please check the edit. `Dual-Pivot Quicksort` is only for arrays of primitives. Added a comparison between the 2 also.

Comment: nice, please correct if(this.value > o.value)  return -1; to:if(this.value > o.value) return 1;