# Why java use quick sort algorithm instead of merge sort in small array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I read sort algorithms that Java used in Arrays, so I opened jar files and read what java used when we call  **Array.sort();**, so I found Java to check if the array's length is less then 286 and use quick sort otherwise use merge sort?

```
   static void sort(int[] a, int left, int right,
                     int[] work, int workBase, int workLen) {
        // Use Quicksort on small arrays
        if (right - left < QUICKSORT_THRESHOLD) {
            sort(a, left, right, true);
            return;
        }
.....
```

Comment: What Java version are you on?

Comment: @Nexevis Java 8 or higher same method

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770230/comparison-between-timsort-and-quicksort and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018332/is-java-7-using-tim-sort-for-the-method-arrays-sort/41129231#41129231.