# Is there a stable sorting algorithm for .Net Doubles faster than O(n log n)?

Tags: .net, algorithm, sorting, double

I need a **stable** sorting algorithm for .Net Doubles that is faster than O(n log n).

I am thinking of Radix sort. However if I understand correctly, it's performance is O(n k) and since I'm sorting Doubles, k = 8. This would make it only faster than an O(n log n) sort (i.e. QuickSort) if n > 2980.  (Is this correct??) In my case n will be more typically around 500 or 1000 but sometimes also much larger. (And yes, this sorting is taking place **very** frequently and based on profiling analysis its speed does matter).

So should I stick with QuickSort or are there any other faster alternatives? How about Bucket sort? I'm looking for good implementations in C# or VB.NET.

Edit: I'm currently using a stable QuickSort implementation.

Edit: See this implementation of Radix for floating point values: http://codercorner.com/RadixSortRevisited.htm. According to this, k would be 9 for Doubles.

Comment: If you are only sorting 500 - 1000 numbers, quicksort should be more than fast enough unless you're sorting thousands of times per second. Could you perhaps give us more background as to why you feel quicksort is inadequate?

Comment: Quicksort is more than fast enough for you if you're only using a few thousand items. You won't even notice it. Also, have you tested Quicksort already (after all you are implying it's too slow)?

Comment: You may want to look at timsort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733073/grokking-timsort

Comment: Obviously I need to sort many times per second otherwise I wouldn't be asking the question. To be clear I'm seeing in my profiling data that this sorting (i'm using a stable quicksort implemenation now) is taking considerable time.

Comment: Try [Bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort). It may be a little bit faster than other alternatives.

Comment: Mergesort is stable and is `O(n log n)`. Quicksort is not stable. I am not sure how this impacts you using `double`.

Comment: @dlev The question was not if quicksort is 'fast enough' for 500-1000 numbers but if faster than O(n log n) sorts exists.

Comment: @Greg timsort's average performance is O(n log n). Best case performance only applies to lists with many already sorted sublists which is not the case in my case.

Comment: @leppie As stated in the original question, I'm looking for something faster than O(n log n).

Answer (score 2):

In fact radix sort for doulbes will have complexity n*k where k is 64 not 8(the classical radix sort uses the binary representation of the numbers). This will hardly be faster for any input. As already stated for small number of input values quick sort will definetely be faster and also note that some of the implementations for std::sort in C++ use a O(n^2) algorithm to finish the sorting of small number of values(really small number) and typically that would be insert sort(take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28C++%29)). So maybe a hybrid between several algorithms will serve you best.

Comment: Actually I'm referring to a byte based Radix implementation where k would be the number of bytes + 1  (See http://www.codercorner.com/RadixSortRevisited.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Radix sort is O(n*k), where k tends to be log(n) - because k is the number of digits, and the number of digits varies with the log of the magnitude of your highest number.

Also, looking at the binary representation of a float or double is unlikely to yield something you can sort by.  You could convert it to a decimal string with a contant number of digits after the decimal point, and radix sort that though, if you avoid scientific notation.

You're probably best off with either the .Net sort method (it's probably been optimized quite a bit), or a timsort.

In asymptotic analysis, you're looking at the shape of a curve, not its absolute position on a graph near the axes.  This is because, for sufficiently large n, the shape matters more than where you cross the axes.

So if you're not sorting huge lists, you could be better off with a lesser sort like quicksort or even insertion sort.

Sorting in a tight loop is rarely a good idea - such designs are usually better off replaced with something using a heap, treap, red-black tree, skip list, splay tree or other log(n) datastructure.

I don't think quicksort is stable, though it can be made so at a bit of a performance penalty.

mergesort is pretty easy to code, is related to timsort, and is stable.  timsort is also stable.

Here's a graph with supporting detail:

[image: linear-linear graph of a few sorts]

Comment: The .Net sort method is *unstable*. (Therefore I have been using a stable quicksort implementation so far).

Comment: Radixsort and O(n) sorting doesn't seem to be what's it's purported to be.

Comment: You might find this of interest: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/sorts/  It's a bunch of sorts in Python, many of them in a performance comparison.  You're not working in Python, but you'd probably find translating from Python to C# pretty mechanical.

Comment: floating pointer numbers can be sorted by Radix sort. See for instance codercorner.com/RadixSortRevisited.htm. Also, in this implementation k is the number of bytes + 1 (so 9 for Double.)

Comment: @ i already have a stable quicksort. mergesort and timsort are both O(n log n)

Comment: I guess you're not hearing me.  Radix sort is O(nlogn) as well.  I never said it couldn't do floats, in fact, I proposed a way of doing it, but a naive radix sort is going to barf on the different portions of a float.

Comment: Interesting that some float implementation details work in a naive radix sort (modulo sign bit), but you're grubbing around in implementation details you shouldn't to get there.  Ask yourself: If radix sort is a stellar sort, why doesn't the Data Warehousing industry use it to blow the doors off their competition?  These people are probably doing the biggest sorts around.

Comment: You really should graph the performance curves you get, when you compare radix sort with timsort, and post it here - and tell us which one is portable as well.

Comment: I've added a radix sort into my sort comparison graph: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/sort-comparison/  It's pretty apparent that radix sort is varying with nlogn, though you may or may not quibble with my methodology.

Comment: I'm hearing you and I see what you mean with radix being more like O(n log n) in reality. Could you perhaps include your comparison graphs in your answer?