# Advanced/Non common Efficient Sorting Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

I know there are some like:

- [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)
- [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)
- [Shell sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_sort)
- [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
- [Heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)
- [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)
- [Bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)
- [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)
- Distribution sort
- Shuffle sort

And there are some impractical ones like:

- [Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)
- RandomSort

Some of the above use comparisons and others do not.

Do you know which other Efficient Algorithms or Techniques for sorting numbers exist?
You can suggest me one even if it is not applicable in real life or it is impractical but it must be efficient, but it would be better if it is a computational solution.

Comment: Once you have collected your algorithms, how about sorting them by speed?

Comment: Which Sort does _not_ use comparisons?

Comment: LOL I think stackoverflow will sort them by ratings

Comment: @Henk bucket sort does not use comparisons. I don't think a sort that doesn't use comparisons can possibly not be some kind of bucket sort.

Comment: Here is a list of not comparison algorithms http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Spaghetti sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_sort):  You cut lengths of spaghetti to lengths corresponding to numbers you want to sort.  Then you tap the bundle of spaghetti down on the table so that all their ends align.  Then you pick out the longest ones in order.  The setup time is long, but the actual sorting time is constant.

Wikipedia has a whole category of [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sorting_algorithms).

Comment: Oh this one sounds interesting =)

Comment: LOL. Speaking as a physicist here, if your working set gets to large (a function of the frictional properties of your spaghetti) this may become unreliable: at some point the tap down procedure may fail due to the force needed to hold the bundle together. I suggest using PTFE speghetti.

Comment: "The setup time is long, but the actual sorting time is constant."  And you get a tasty and nutritious meal out of it when you've finished.

Comment: @GMan, the sorting time is constant - one tap, bam, and you're done. Reading the results is linear.

Comment: Actually, the sorting time is proportional to the length of the longest spaghetti. It takes time for the rest of the spaghetti to move that distance, remember.

Comment: Pancake sort sounds more delicious.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting

Comment: @itowlson: not quite - you still have to cook it. At which point, of course, extracting the correct order becomes significantly more difficult.

Comment: Does this need physx or what ? :D

Answer (score 3):

Python uses an algorithm called [timsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154504/is-timsort-general-purpose-or-python-specific).

Comment: timsort is a mergesort. Various hoops have been jumped through to insure against bad worst-case performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are [sorting networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network), which can be an efficient way of sorting if you know in advance how many items you have to sort.

Answer (score 1):

[natural mergesort](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort#Natural_mergesort) is different enough from "plain mergesort" to be worth mentioning separately (just like [quickersort](http://thomas.baudel.name/Visualisation/VisuTri/quicksort.html) is enough of a variation on quicksort to be worth mentioning, but even more so).  Python's timsort, which Ned's answer mentions, is based on natural mergesort, btw.

Oh, and, there's [Dobosiewicz](http://thomas.baudel.name/Visualisation/VisuTri/dobosort.html) sort AKA "comb sort", which "stands to bubblesort as shellsort stands to insertion sort" (nothing especially efficient, but still worth mentioning).

Answer (score 1):

A nice variation of Heapsort is [Smoothsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort). It performs better than Heapsort if the data is already almost sorted (O(n) instead of O(n log n)).